# Configuring an AccessDeniedHandler in order to process an invalid csrf token

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I am in reference to Spring Security documentation about configuring CSRF protection:

> Instead by default Spring Security’s CSRF protection will produce an
>   HTTP 403 access denied. This can be customized by configuring the
>   AccessDeniedHandler to process InvalidCsrfTokenException differently.

see here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure

I am unsure how to configure my handler in order to deal with the invalid CSRF token.

```
private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new AccessDeniedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                // TODO: deal with InvalidCsrfTokenException
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
            }
        };
    }
```

I use angular on the client side to communicate with my Spring app in REST.

What is the best way to deal with stale/invalid CSRF tokens?

Should I use the the `AccessDeniedHandler` in order to add a custom http response header indicating that the CSRF token is invalid and process that on the client side? But how can I request a fresh CSRF token from JS?

Is there another and better way to proceed and how can I

> process the InvalidCsrfTokenException differently

?

Answer (score 4):

If you provide a detailed error message then use the `AccessDeniedHandler`. The handler manage the `InvalidCsrfTokenException` and `MissingCsrfTokenException`

And why do you want to generate the csrf token? Everytime you request a site spring will generate it for you. But if you really want to implement an own csrf strategie take a look at the [CsrfAuthenticationStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfAuthenticationStrategy.html)

Spring call this class everytime in the [SessionManagementFilter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/SessionManagementFilter.html)